# How to migrate to different foreign key with Prisma without data loss?

Tags: mysql, prisma

I have two database entities in my `schema.prisma`:

```
model Currency {
  id              Int                   @id @default(autoincrement())
  code            String                @unique @db.Char(3)
  symbol          String                @db.VarChar(5)
  symbolAltNarrow String?               @db.VarChar(5)
  Translation     CurrencyTranslation[]
  Country         Country[]
}

model CurrencyTranslation {
  id               Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  type             TranslationsType
  displayName      String
  displayNameOne   String?
  displayNameFew   String?
  displayNameMany  String?
  displayNameOther String?
  Currency         Currency         @relation(fields: [currencyId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  currencyId       Int

  @@index([currencyId])
}
```

As you can see, `CurrencyTranslation` references `Currency` by id which is not stable (`id` may change if I truncate the table by wishing to repopulate it, and CurrencyTranslation row would no longer be connected to any currency after that). I want to change it to reference the `code` column instead, but how can I do so without data loss? I cannot drop the foreign key column `currencyId`. Is there a way in Prisma to do what I want?